# Lock screen is always ON even if I switch it off by pressing the power button

Tags: samsung, lock-screens, android-10

I have been facing a problem with my Samsung Galaxy M30. **FYI** The power button working totally fine(I can reboot using it and shut the phone down, no problem with my power button). But as I put my phone to sleep, the screen does go off but the problem is that after 2 or 3 seconds **the lock screen of the phone automatically turns ON**(without touching it or shaking, I haven't enabled any gestures) and continuously glows all the time, it doesn't turn off. I tried to shut down my phone but it didn't help me. How to troubleshoot this? This problem drains my battery too fast, I don't know what happened to my phone. Can it be a virus or malware problem(I have also tried to scan my phone for any malware but it also couldn't help me)?

**Please help me.**

Comment: This has been asked a few times in slightly different ways but none have a working answer.

Comment: I don't actually know what to do, to resolve a little bit or to save my battery I just used a screen dimmer that turns the screen opaque up to 95%. I don't have any other option right now